# « Twofold » en français

Tags: traduction

Existe-t-il un autre mot que double pour rendre en français le mot anglais *twofold* ?

Selon la réponse reçue l'on peut employer *en deux volets*. Donc, comment peut-on employer *en deux volets* dans la phrase ci-dessous (les cas échéant) ?

> This negative aspect has a twofold bearing.

(qui pourrait être bein sûr traduite par

> Cet aspect négatif a une double incidence.

)

La phrase

> Cet aspect négatif a une incidence en deux volets.

est-elle idiomatique ?

En outre, peut-on traduire

> The purpose of this paper is twofold.

par la phrase ci-dessous ?

> L'objectif de cet article est en deux volets.

Je n'ai rien du tout contre « double ». Il me paraît simplement que **twofold** est un peu plus soutenu que son traduction française standard **double**.

Comment: Ça dépend du contexte, mais qu'as-tu contre « double » ? Il convient bien dans ces phrases.

Comment: Rien du tout contre « double » bien sûr. Il me paraissait simplement que twofold est un peu plus soutenu que son interprétation française standard « double » :-)!

Comment: Note that another meaning of Nfold is indeed just multiplied by N (instead of having N components as here), and then I think doublé, etc. would suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COMPLÉMENT DE RÉPONSE _ à propos de la possibilité de dire « objectif en deux volets »

Il semble qu'il y ait du vrai dans l'opinion qu'il puisse y avoir peu de justification de l'usage de « deux volets », mais seulement dans certains cas; le cas construit suivant (donc pas réel mais suffisamment raisonnable pour servir à un examen) est l'un de ceux-ci ; il montre que l'usage de « double » est préférable.

- Nous avions un double objectif en faisant cette ascension; prouver que l'on peut se passer de l'usage normal de l'une de ses deux jambes pour parvenir au sommet et que c'est possible pour des personnes avec cette sorte de handicap en un temps, sinon record, du moins très comparable à celui d'autres grimpeurs amateurs.

*On distingue bien deux impératifs mais ils sont essentiellement confondus en une seule action. Il s'agit de suppléer au handicap d'une part et de l'autre d'effectuer cela en y mettant le moins de temps possible. On peut difficilement parler de deux facettes séparées.*

Cependant, Je ne vois pas ce qui empêcherait d'avoir recours à ce concept dans d'autres cas, c'est à dire ces cas dans lesquels il existe deux parties bien distinctes avec une articulation. Voici un autre exemple construit.

- Nous avions un objectif en deux volets en repensant la chaine de production : d'un côté faire le nécessaire pour réduire au maximum le temps de montage de l'appareil, de l'autre, réduire au maximum le nombre des manipulations par des opérateurs humains; le problème a souvent été que les deux buts ne sont pas toujours compatibles.

*Pour ce contexte différent, il n'est pas difficile de concevoir qu'un aspect de l'entreprise est limité à effectuer des modifications qui portent sur l'accélération, bien qu'accessoirement un problème de manipulation par des opérateurs puisse occasionnellement y être lié, et qu'un autre aspect, indépendant de la question de l'accélération, tout au moins en partie, porte sur un besoin de diminuer la main d'œuvre, celui-ci, inversement, pouvant avoir des conséquence dans le domaine de la rapidité du montage.*

La justification de l'utilisation de « en deux volets » plutôt que de « double » est beaucoup une question de contexte.

Answer (score 5):

On peut simplement utiliser *deux*:

> Cet aspect négatif a deux incidences.
>
> Cet article vise deux objectifs.

Answer (score 0):

`Twofold => en deux volets`

`Threefold => en trois volets`

etc,

Ma réponse comprend donc deux volets,

la [définition de `volet`](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/volet/82453) du Larousse:

> Partie ayant son unité, sa cohésion, et venant s'articuler à d'autres dans un ensemble plus vaste : Une politique sociale en trois volets.

et la [définition de `twofold`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twofold) du Cambridge Dictionnary:

> having two parts

Comment: Merci vivement. Alors, peut-on dire p. ex. **Le but de ce message est en deux volets** ?

Comment: Je pense que oui ... sans relation avec ta question, personelement je remplacerai `but` par `objectif`.

Comment: C'est noté:-!) Merci encore.

Comment: @dimitris Non: « deux volets » signifie deux parties. Un document peut avoir deux volets. Un objectif ne peut pas avoir deux volets.

Comment: Merci Gilles pour le downvote :) En fait tu objecte plus la phrase d'example plutot que la traduction de `twofold`. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twofold et https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/volet comme references.

Comment: On peut donc utiliser  deux et double. Or, peut-on finalement utiliser deux volets ou non ? Pour que je puisse accepter la réponse.

Comment: Ben pour moi oui, mais bon apparement je fais pas l’unanimité :) Pour moi un objectif peut avoir 2 volets, pour @Gilles non!? Je peux pas vraiment être l’arbitre dans ce cas. Il faudrais un troisième vote indépendant:)

Comment: @ zeFrenchy On attend:-)!

Comment: On attend quoi?

Comment: @zeFrenchy Je voulais dire que l'on attend une 3e opinion :-)!

Comment: Oui @dimitris ... attendons :)